# How to draw a bitmap with Scala?

Tags: scala, graphics, bitmap

I would like to draw a bitmap, manually specifying colour of every point of it (in other words, the task is to save a 2D array of RGB values to a PNG (or some other lossless true-colour bitmap format) file).

It would be also nice to have a function to print some text (with a given font of a given size) pieces on top of the image at given coordinates.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Java standard library `ImageIO` class. It offers a static `write` method that can, for example, encode and write a `RenderedImage` to an output stream in PNG format. For the `RenderedImage`, you can easily use the `BufferedImage` class. It offers a `setRGB` method for directly manipulating the colors of individual pixels. Alternatively, you can also call `BufferedImage.getGraphics()`, which returns an instance of `Graphics` that you can draw any kind of shape or text on, or even whole GUI components, just like with any AWT component.

This is regular Java stuff. Scala does not offer any special wrappers for that, and I also doubt it would be worth the effort.

Comment: Absolutely. This is trivial stuff.  Interop is one of scala's strengths, and theres little benefit in writing a wrapper here.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a java library such as the [Java Advanced Imaging API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/iio.html). It's well documented.

Comment: Do you mean there are really no Scala native (or wrapper) implementations of such a primitive task?

Comment: Processing from processing.org is a very nice Java library for 2D stuff, and fully operable with Scala.

Comment: I think using Processing for such a primitive task is like using heavy artillery against mosquitoes.

Comment: @Ivan: There is no need for a wrapper. If you disagree, write one. ;)

Comment: @Kim Then simply +1 his comment.